# Asymptotic expansion of $(1+\epsilon)^{s/\epsilon}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series, epsilon-delta

I have taken the logarithm of this expression and computed the Taylor expansion of the $\log(1+\epsilon)$ term but by doing this we're required to calculate powers of this series when using the definition of the exponential function, but this gives a combinatorical mess.

eg. $(1+\epsilon)^{s/\epsilon}=\exp\left(s\right)\exp\left(s\delta\right),$
where $\delta=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \epsilon^n}{n+1}.$

I was wondering if anyone knows of a general formula for the coefficient of $\epsilon^n$ of $(1+\epsilon)^{s/\epsilon}$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Any known papers on this topic too?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am stuck with the general formula.

For the first terms, it is quite simple : starting with $$A=(1+\epsilon )^{s/\epsilon }$$ $$\log(A)=\frac{s }{\epsilon }\log (1+\epsilon)=\frac{s }{\epsilon }\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\epsilon^n} n=s \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\epsilon^{n-1}} n$$ Now, using $A=e^{\log(A)}$ and using Taylor series again leads to $$A=e^s\left(1-\frac{s  }{2}\epsilon+\frac{s (3 s+8)}{24}  \epsilon ^2-\frac{s(s+2)(s+6)
   }{48}  \epsilon ^3+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right) \right)$$ So, $$A=e^s \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n P_n(s) \epsilon^n$$ where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $s$.

Comment: Claude my friend!  How are you?  +1 for this.  I was just going to write a similar solution, but you're too fast for me.  -Mark

Comment: Hey, Mark ! Any idea for the general form ? I am just stuck !

Comment: Claude, I haven't pursued developing the general form - if such a general form is tractable.

Comment: IMHO, the most one can have to complete @Claude's analysis, is a *name* for this uniquely defined sequence of polynomials $(P_n(s))$ and a recursion to compute them one by one...

Comment: For example, the initial conditions $P_0(0)=1$, $P_n(0)=0$ for every $n\geqslant1$, and the recursions $$P'_n(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{P_k(s)}{n-k+1},$$ for every $n\geqslant0$, fully determine $(P_n(s))$. Some properties follow directly, such as each $P_n$ having degree $n$...

Comment: @Did. This is very interesting, for sure ! May I ask how you did arrive at this beautiful point ?

Comment: Simply following your lead, one can differentiate the identity $$(1+\epsilon )^{s/\epsilon }=e^s \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n P_n(s) \epsilon^n$$ with respect to $s$. This yields $$\frac{\log(1+\epsilon)}\epsilon e^s \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n P_n(s) \epsilon^n=\frac{\log(1+\epsilon)}\epsilon (1+\epsilon )^{s/\epsilon }=e^s \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n P'_n(s) \epsilon^n,$$ that is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\epsilon^n}{n+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n P_n(s) \epsilon^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n P'_n(s) \epsilon^n,$$ and it remains to identify the coefficients of $\epsilon^n$ in the LHS and in the RHS.

Comment: @Did. It becomes so simple when you see the solution ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: *The first sum in the last identity in my previous comment should start at $n=1$, not $n=0$, sorry about the typo.

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1801927/).

Comment: @Did. I saw it before your last comment arrived. It would be very interesting to know ! "Simple" problems leading to "big" problems, once more ! Cheers.

Comment: Slow down, you young soul full of enthusiasm... Most probably this is a well known family of polynomials that I failed to identify only because my ignorance is abysmal...